# Python error when pulling random URL from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I am new to python and still learning.

I am just playing around with small scripts I am creating for fun to learn, here is what I got.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\16239\\youtubebot\\chromedriver")


videos = [
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COAdbTDTDFc"
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_2wemVUQnc"
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8fODOFiBq0"
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmgT01e1sGQ"
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eqEuBp3jJw"
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09IRNL2TsHM"
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUIugt-GsbY"
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqlBwWX218s"
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrKafd3U4TY"
]

random_video = random.randint(0,8)
sleep_time = random.randint(60,120)

for i in range(7000):
    print("Running the Video for {} time".format(i))
    driver.get(videos[random_video])
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    driver.quit()
```

the issue is when I run it I am getting the error.

```
driver.get(videos[random_video])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have 9 in the videos list and the random_video variable is calling 0 - 8 and I cant figure out the error. please help

Answer (score 2):

There is no comma `,` at the end of video URL in your videos list.

```
videos = [
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COAdbTDTDFc",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_2wemVUQnc",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8fODOFiBq0",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmgT01e1sGQ",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eqEuBp3jJw",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09IRNL2TsHM",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUIugt-GsbY",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqlBwWX218s",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrKafd3U4TY"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not separate the videos with `,` python thinks it only has 1 element

```
videos = [
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COAdbTDTDFc",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_2wemVUQnc",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8fODOFiBq0",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmgT01e1sGQ",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eqEuBp3jJw",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09IRNL2TsHM",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUIugt-GsbY",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqlBwWX218s",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrKafd3U4TY"
]
```

by the way, <s>`randint` is `(inclusive, exclusive)` so the last video will never be picked AND</s> you format the **number of iteration** not the time like you are looking to do.

Comment: ```randint()``` is both "inclusive". [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

Comment: I must have confused it with another rand function - thanks :)